# LSTMCell parameters is not shown Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, pytorch, backpropagation

I have the following code:

```
class myLSTM(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, input_size, output_size, hidden_size, num_layers):
    super(myLSTM, self).__init__()
    self.input_size = input_size + 1 
    self.output_size = output_size
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.layers = []
    new_input_size = self.input_size
    for i in xrange(num_layers):
        self.layers.append(LSTMCell(new_input_size, hidden_size))
        new_input_size = hidden_size
    self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
    self.softmax = nn.Softmax()

def forwardLayers(self, input, hns, cns, layers):
    new_hns = []
    new_cns = []
    (hn, cn) = layers[0](input, (hns[0], cns[0]))
    new_hns.append(hn)
    new_cns.append(cn)
    for i in xrange(1, len(layers)):
        (hn, cn) = layers[i](hn, (hns[i], cns[i]))
        new_hns.append(hn)
        new_cns.append(cn)
    return hn, (new_hns, new_cns)

def forward(self, input, hx):
    actions = []
    hns, cns = hx
    action = torch.Tensor([[0.0]])
    for i in range(len(input)):
        new_input = input[i]
        new_input = new_input.view(1, -1)
        output, (hns, cns) = self.forwardLayers(new_input, hns, cns, self.layers)
        output = self.softmax(self.linear(output))

    return output
```

Now when I call the following code to see the parameters of my network:

```
for name, param in myLSTM_object.named_parameters():
        if param.requires_grad:
            print name, param.data
```

What I get is:

```
linear.weight tensor([[ 0.5042, -0.6984],
    [ 0.0721, -0.4060]])
linear.bias tensor([ 0.6968, -0.4649])
```

So, it completely misses the parameters of LSTMCell. Does this mean the parameters of LSTMCell is not trained. What should I do to see LSTMCell parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to be expected - storing modules in `list`, `dict`, `set` or other python containers does not register them with the module owning said `list`, etc. To make your code work, use [`nn.ModuleList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#modulelist) instead. It's as simple as modifying your `__init__` code to use

```
layers = []
new_input_size = self.input_size
for i in xrange(num_layers):
    layers.append(LSTMCell(new_input_size, hidden_size))
    new_input_size = hidden_size
self.layers = nn.ModuleList(layers)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Does this mean in my code, the parameters were not updated for LSTMCeell?

Comment: I would appreciate if you could answer my previous comment. That is very important for me.

Comment: Essentially the only difference is the one you found: `named_parameters()` (and `parameters()`) will not return the parameters of your `LSTMCell`s. This has the crucial consequence, that if you construct optimizers by passing them `model.parameters()`, the optimizer will not be aware of `LSTMCell` parameters and not update the during training. Using `ModuleList` fixes this.

Comment: Can you also answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55188698/understanding-when-to-use-python-list-in-pytorch? Thank you so much!