# Understanding when to use python list in Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

Basically as this thread discusses [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/the-difference-in-usage-between-nn-modulelist-and-python-list/7744/2), you cannot use python list to wrap your sub-modules (for example your layers); otherwise, Pytorch is not going to update the parameters of the sub-modules inside the list. Instead you should use `nn.ModuleList` to wrap your sub-modules to make sure their parameters are going to be updated. Now I have also seen codes like following where the author uses python list to calculate the loss and then do `loss.backward()` to do the update (in reinforce algorithm of RL). Here is the code:

```
 policy_loss = []
    for log_prob in self.controller.log_probability_slected_action_list:
        policy_loss.append(- log_prob * (average_reward - b))
    self.optimizer.zero_grad()
    final_policy_loss = (torch.cat(policy_loss).sum()) * gamma
    final_policy_loss.backward()
    self.optimizer.step()
```

Why using the list in this format works for updating the parameters of modules but the first case does not work? I am very confused now. If I change in the previous code `policy_loss = nn.ModuleList([])`, it throws an exception saying that tensor float is not sub-module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what `Module`s are. A `Module` stores parameters and defines an implementation of the forward pass.

You're allowed to perform arbitrary computation with tensors and parameters resulting in other new tensors. `Modules` need not be aware of those tensors. You're also allowed to store lists of tensors in Python lists. When calling `backward` it needs to be on a scalar tensor thus the sum of the concatenation. These tensors are losses and not parameters so they should not be attributes of a `Module` nor wrapped in a `ModuleList`.